# Android OpenCV best algorithm for finding object in picture

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, optimization, detection

Having looked at the available features of OpenCV, it seems to me that theoretically speaking, there are a couple of ways to find an object in a picture.

1. Use Fourier Transform: if the object you're looking for has stripes or some sort of repetition
2. Use derivatives to identify edges
3. Use cascading classifiers

In practically, how effective are each of these methods at finding an object? How do the speeds of each implementation compare? At the end of the day, I'm looking for an oval object with some repeating patterns (kind of like an American football) in my picture.

Cheers,
Kevin

Comment: There are many other techniques to _detect_ an object... Post a sample image of the object alone, and one that contains that object. Also, it's always the _same_ footballt? Or you want to detect all American footballs? Your question is too broad right now

Comment: So I want to detect American footballs in general, if you go to a store and buy a football, the app should be able to identify it. The algorithm should work even if there are small differences like team logos on the footballs. An example image would be any image of a football found on google. Thanks!